# Какие угрозы может нести в себе вставка произвольного javascript в header / footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-events, site

Делаем условный конструктор сайтов, предоставляем пользователям возможность вставлять код в header и footer своего сайта. После сохранения эти коды появляются в соответствующей области сайта. Подскажите какие проблемы это может за собой повлечь ? Может ли javascript код нанести вред сайту или серверу ? Есть ли какая - то методика защиты (за исключением белых и черных списков) ?

Comment: Не советую давать пользователю вставлять код, если вы хотите дать возможность к примеру размещать футер, сделайте конструктор из выбора столбцов, макета, дайте ему визуальный редактор с настройкой добавлять только текст, маркированный и нумерованный список ну и к примеру форматирование. Также можно воспользоваться компонентами фильтрации кода перед сохранением данных в базу.

Comment: Ну если вставляет владелец сайт, то как бы что вставит то и будет. Но тут может быть проблема, что если можно делиться своими шаблонами, то можно воровать аккаунты через куки. Хотя, кому нужен аккаунт от конструктора сайта

Comment: Конструктор на Вашем хостинге или на чужом? Если Вы предоставляете этот конструктор вместе с хостингом как некий бесплатный сервис, то это одно. А если я покупаю конструктор и устанавливаю его на своём хостинге, то это совершенно другое. Как уже сказали выше, разрешение на вставку JS на своём хостинге - это потенциальная проблема.

Comment: Конструктор на нашем сервере, каждый новый сайт порождает новый docker контейнер. Вставка кода - вынужденная мера. Так как наши пользователи зачастую вставляют гугл/яндекс метрики, подключают встроенных помощников по примеру jivosite и тд. Так как наборов этих скриптов очень много, было решено не писать под каждый модуль код, а дать возможность людям самим вставлять код, надеясь на их порядочность. Ну также учитываем, что сайты - это некие лендинги, регистрироваться там нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Если пользователи делят домен с вами или с другими пользователями, то с помощью JS пользователи могут саботировать друг друга и/или хозяина домена. Способов много.

В любом случае, учтите, что вставка кастомного JS даёт вашим пользователям неограниченные возможноти изобретательно испортить работу своего сайта или подвергнуть его риску. Рекомендую подумать, есть ли у вас ресурс реагировать на ошибки вызванные сторонними скриптами.